# Conversion of Data Class from "Factor" to "TS" class

Tags: r, excel, csv

I am trying to `plot` stock price (Time Series) for PNB (Nifty Index) over a period of 1 year in order to study the patterns. Attached is the data for stock Price in `CSV` format.
But when I am trying to convert the class of this data from `CSV` file using `zoo (xts) package`,

Note: xts is subset of zoo package.

`d<-xts(f$Close.Price,order.by=as.Date(f$Date),format="%m/%d/%y")`

Error in charToDate(x) :
  `character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
where f is the dataframe which is the reading the .csv file`

I have also tried with date variable with the following command and gives me below error,

> s<-as.Date(f$Date, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
>   s
>     [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
>    [29] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
>    [57] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
>    [85] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
>   [113] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
>   [141] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
>   [169] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
>   [197] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
>   [225] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
>   [253] NA

I am getting NA for the dates.
In other words, I am not able to convert the class of f$Date into "ts" class.
Please help me to convert the data into the correct format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing it in two steps, using `lubridate`:

```
library(lubridate)
df <- read.csv("stockdata.csv", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)
df$timedata <- mdy(df$timedata)
```

`mdy()` will take a 'vector of suspected dates'.  You can specify the arrangement of dates with `ymd()`, `mdy()`, `dmy()`, and more.  Look up the documentation for `lubridate` for more.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried the above command and it works. But there is an issue, it is only working for dmy() and dates are in reverse order. Please see the below output > x<-mdy(f$Date)
Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found. 
> x<-dmy(f$Date)
> x
  [1] "2015-02-20" "2015-02-23" "2015-02-24" "2015-02-25" "2015-02-26" "2015-02-27"
  [7] "2015-02-28" "2015-03-02" "2015-03-03" "2015-03-04" "2015-03-05" "2015-03-09"

Comment: That looks like the data in `f$Date` is not uniform.  In that case, I would isolate those rows, change their format, and plug them back in at the appropriate index.

Comment: Thank you, Raphael for your prompt response and help. I appreciate your support on this. Is there any way I can upload a .csv file here and you can have a look in that file.

Comment: I don't know if SO allows uploading files - I haven't seen it yet.  You can post a separate question about changing those dates, if you like.  I would search around for your question first though!